# How to prevent socket.io executing an event for all users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

whenever I press a button on the client-side to send a emit a request to the server, that button executes for all connected users. I'd like to make it so that it only emits to the current user. is there any way I can do this?

client.js

```
handleForm = () => {
        socket.emit("request-uid");
        socket.on("uid", (uid) => {
            socket.emit("validate-data", {
                title: this.state.title,
                price: this.state.price,
                email: this.state.email,
                description: this.state.description,
                contact: this.state.contact,
                tags: this.state.tags,
            });
        });
    };
socket.on("refresh", () =>{
    alert("test!");
});
```

server.js

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("user connected!");
    socket.on("request-uid", () => {
        io.emit("uid", crypto.randomBytes(4).toString("hex"));
    });

    socket.on("validate-data", (data) => {
            io.to(socket.id).emit("refresh");
        
    });
});
```

when I click the button that executes the `handleForm()` function it emits the sockets to every user that is currently on the site, regardless of whether or not they pressed the button.

even when I use `io.to(socket.id)` on the server side it sends it to everyone as well, I'm guessing this is because "validate-data" is running, and it sends a unique socket to emit to all users.

I just want it to send a request to the user that pressed the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io.emit('uid')` sends the `uid` event to all client sockets, and then in the callback each client emits its own `validate-data` to the server. Change `io.emit('uid')` to `socket.emit('uid')` and you can also simplify `io.to(socket.id).emit('refresh')` to `socket.emit('refresh')`.

Comment: Sadly that doesnt seem to work, is there a way to change socket.emit("validate-data") to make it so that its only emitting it from that one user?

Comment: @Pylot `socket.emit('validate-data')` is client-side. The problem is that `io.emit('uid')` emits a unique id to ALL clients each time ANY client emits `request-uid`, and then ALL clients respond with `validate-data`.

Comment: @Pylot Did you make sure to restart the server and refresh all clients after making the suggested changes?

Comment: ohhhh! i see what you mean! your absolutely right, changing the UID fixes it! thank you very much, that seems to have fixed it :)